# Can I advertise for non-halal products?

Tags: halal-haram, money, business

I’m making a website to advertise for hotels, restaurants, POIs etc. Each place has to pay a fee to advertise. 
What I want to know is if I can have adverts for non-halal places on the website if they are clearly marked as non-halal and the fee they pay goes straight to a charity, I will not handle any of the money. The reason to have non-halal places is to get more users. I don’t however receive any money directly from there being more users. There won’t be places such as nightclubs and bars etc.

Would this be permissible and would my income be halal?

Comment: Is it possible some of the stores sell alcohol?

Comment: Yes, it is @TheZ

Answer (score -1):

No,with advertising these places you help them to get money from not halal actions.So in a way you participate to their sins